# How does Groovy resolve method calls with whitespaces

Tags: groovy

I am wondering why Groovy compiler isn't capable to correctly resolve the following calls

```
a = { p -> p }
b = { p -> p }

a b 1
```

I would expect that to be interpreted correctly as

```
a(b(1))
```

Or is there any syntax that could be interpreted differently?

Interestingly enough this yields the right result

```
a b { 1 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It tries to evaluate that as:

```
a( b ).1
```

The way I imagine it, is as if it were a list of symbols, and `collate( 2 )` was called on them...

```
def list = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ]
def pairs = list.collate( 2 )
```

All entries in this list with 2 values are a method/parameter pair, and any single elements left at the end are property access calls

So `a b c d e` would be evaluated as: `a( b ).c( d ).e`

Your second example is an interesting edge case.  I am guessing that because of the final closure, the call to `b( Closure )` takes precedence, and so is executed first, followed by the call to `a` on the result.

So given:

```
a = { p -> p + 10 }
b = { c -> c() * 5 }

a b { 1 }
```

The result is `15`

Comment: I learn more by reading Tim's response's than from reading most books!